# HTML Form Using JavaScript Valildation

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I working on Javascript validation task as i am beginner in Javascript i was stuck in Js validation code [codepen](https://codepen.io/asiyaf09/pen/PoqErWj?editors=0110).Can, Anyone Please help out of this and point me in right direction.
Thanks in advance.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
function formValidation() {
  var firstname = document.getElementById('product');
if (firstname.value.length == 0) {
  document.getElementById('head').innerText = "*    All fields are mandatory *"; 
  firstname.focus();
return false;
}
if (inputAlphabet(firstname, "* For your name     please use alphabets only *")) { 
   return true;
}
  return false;
}

function textNumeric(inputtext, alertMsg) {
    var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if (inputtext.value.match(numericExpression)) {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementByClass('price').innerText = alertMsg;
        inputtext.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
function inputAlphabet(inputtext, alertMsg) {
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if (inputtext.value.match(alphaExp)) {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('product').innerText = alertMsg; 
     inputtext.focus();
     return false;
    }
}


});
```

```css
body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.product-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 100px;
}

input#product {
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

input.price {
    max-width: 227px;
    padding: 5px 4px;
    width: 100%;
}
input.qnty {
    max-width: 235px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 4px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Product Order</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
 <script src="custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="product-container">
  <form action="submit" method="POST">
      Product Name: <input type="text" name="name" value=""  required id="product" ><br><br>
      Unit Price: <input type="number" name="Price" value= "" required class="price" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?"><br><br>
      Quantity: <input type="number" name="Quantity" value="" min="1" max="10" required class="qnty price"><br><br>      
      <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Get Total Amount">
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn javascript before jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the same thing I was doing when I started using jQuery... mixing JavaScript with jQuery.

You don't need to create a function to validate the form.  I'd first change your submit button to this:

```
<button type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

Then use jQuery to listen for the button click:

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
  var product = $('#product').val();
  var price = $('.price').val(); 
  var name = $('#name').val(); 

  // check if name input has a value, if blank, then display error message
  if(name == "") {
    alert('You must enter a name');
    return false;
  }
  if(product == '//whatever you want to check here') {
    // display message
  }
  if(price == '// check if the input is blank') {
    // return error message
  }
  else {
   // do something
  }
});
```

The if/else inside your button click is your validation.

Comment: thanks for all your support but still am not getting also I have to validate using javascript. please help me to solve.

Comment: You don't need javascript functions.  In your code, you are using "if (firstname.value.length == 0)" to check if the firstname is blank.  In my solution, all I did was "if(name == "")" which does the same thing using JQuery.  You can also use JQuery to check if the name contains numbers.  I think you have to do something like "if(name.isNumeric())" or something like that.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Remove all of your javascript functions, change your input button into a button and create variables like I did above.  Try to alert (or console.log()) each variable so you can understand what the button click is doing.  Then try using the if/else statements to validate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I see a ton of errors in your very small code. Your Jquery code looks very bad. You are creating functions but never using them, You don't have to create functions for form validation. You can use **Jquery event listeners** to check if the user has performed some action like (submit, Focus, Blur etc.,) and when you receive the event you have to perform an action and clearly **innerText does not work on input boxes**. Go through this article on [form validation using Jquery](https://www.batoi.com/support/articles/article/validate-a-form-using-jquery). 
You should do basic google search before posting a question here.

Comment: thanks for sharing your knowledge, I will go through that